# Spherical human floating in zero-g, tended to by robots

Tags: story-identification, soft-sci-fi

This is an (I think short) story. I think I read it in some story compilation.

This human is in the far future and by his time evolution has caused people to become enormously fat (large and nearly spherical), so much that they are unable to support their own weight or make use of their limbs. Instead, robots tend to their every need. Btw, I'm not sure, but maybe only one human has remained by that time.

The fat human entertains himself by doing mental time tourism - he enters the mind of people from our present. The protagonist is one such person who has his mind entered. He can feel it.

The story in question was partially a love story I think.

Comment: Why does this remind me of the spherical chickens in a vacuum joke...?

Comment: Right up to the mental tourism, this reminded me of John Varley's *The Golden Globe*.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

["The Parasite"](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?52070) by Arthur C. Clarke, published in 1953

Omega is an immortal living in the far future. He lives in a spherical zero gee room, tended by robots. One difference with your description is he looks like a lemur, not a fat human.

He is very very bored.

So he projects his mind into the past to feed on the emotions of humans like us.

Comment: You can find an audio reading of it at https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xKngFVwDQFs and there's a review at http://arthur-clarke-fansite.blogspot.com/2007/04/parasite-paranormal-weird-obviously.html that does a nice summary and adds recommendations of similar stories.

Comment: @user14111: I'm not nearly as good as you are at finding such things. :)

Comment: @user14111: I can't find it... link pls?